# Firebase Analytics Audiences are not logged

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, target-audience

I can't see statistics for my user in Firebase Analytics Audiences. Audiences are built before fetching events. I can see those logs in Logcat and DebugView. Over 24h have passed.

This is what I do in my Android App:

```
// in onCreate
firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);            

//in onResume
firebaseAnalytics.setUserId("10101010");
firebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty("client_number", "10101010");
```

In tab User Properties I have defined client_number.
In Logcat and DebugView I can see those logs.

```
D/FA: Setting user property (FE): _id, 10101010
D/FA: Setting user property (FE): client_number, 10101010
```

and DebugView:

[image]

And finally I have constructed Audiences (before trigger events), where:

- user_id exactly matches 10101010
- client_number exactly matches 10101010 at any point

  [image][image]

But the Audiences are unfortunately empty (< 10 Users). The number of All Users is 59 (so it's more than mandatory 10). Any suggestion what went wrong?

Comment: So, to be clear, do all 59 users of your app have a user ID and client of 10101010?

Comment: No, every user has unique user id/client number. In those 59 users can be duplicate cause I install/uninstall app for user 10101010 (development reasons). But app was installed for more than 10 different users (it means different user id/client number).

Comment: So it's not just about having more than 10 users total. You need to have at least 10 users in the same audience. It sounds like maybe you haven't done that yet.

Comment: @ToddKerpelman thanks for your reply. As you can see I log user id and client number always together and those values are equal. Finally, after some days, client number was logged in my audience (but user id was not). I'm not sure what Firebase intention was to give the possibility to create audience using user id. For me, it is completely useless. Maybe it's just my misunderstanding. But it allowed me to understand that the tool that I need is just BigQuery. Thanks for your time.